# JQuery + PHP contact form multiple checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a little problem with my contact form. I added multiple checkbox but once proceeded the email only shows 1 when I check all of them.
I might be missing something.
Here is my code if anyone can help me.
Thanks

HTML

```
<div id="contact_form">
<div style="color:#000;" id="contact_results"></div>
<div id="contact_body">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" id="nom" placeholder="Nom">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prenom" id="prenom" placeholder="Prenom">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="annee" id="annee" placeholder="Année de naissance">
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id1" value="Habille">Habillé</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id2" value="Sexy">Sexy (+18)</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id3" value="Lingerie - Maillot de bain">Lingerie/Maillot de bain (+18)</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id4" value="Nue cache">Nue caché (+18)</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="id[]" id="id5" value="Nue non cache">Nue non caché (+18)</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ville" id="ville" placeholder="ville">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Votre message"></textarea>
 </div>
<button type="submit" id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Envoyer</button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

JQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit_btn").click(function() {     
var proceed = true;
$("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
$(this).css('border-color',''); 
if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
$(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
}
var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
$(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
}   
});
if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
{
post_data = {
'user_nom'      : $('input[name=nom]').val(),
'user_prenom'   : $('input[name=prenom').val(),
'user_message'      : $('textarea[name=message]').val(),
'user_ville'    : $('input[name=ville]').val(),
'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(),
'user_theme' : $("input[name='id[]']:checked").val(),
'user_annee'    : $('input[name=annee]').val(),
        };
$.post('modelc.php', post_data, function(response){  
if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
}else{
output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
//reset values in all input fields
$("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
$("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
}
$("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
}, 'json');
}
});
$("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
$(this).css('border-color',''); 
$("#result").slideUp();
});
});
```

PHP

```
    <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
$headers = 'From: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
if($_POST)
{
$to_email       = "hello@originsphotography.eu"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'Erreur', 
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
} 

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_nom       = filter_var($_POST["user_nom"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_prenom    = filter_var($_POST["user_prenom"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_message      = filter_var($_POST["user_message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_ville      = filter_var($_POST["user_ville"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$user_annee    = filter_var($_POST["user_annee"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$user_theme    = $_POST["user_theme"];
$subject        = "Contact site internet";
$from           = "www.originsphotography.eu";

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_nom)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Le champ est trop court ou vide'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Veuillez entrer une adresse email valide'));
    die($output);
}

//email body
$message_body = "Nom : ".$user_nom."\r\n\r\nPrénom : ".$user_prenom."\r\n\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\n\r\nMessage : ".$user_message."\r\n\r\nVille : ".$user_ville."\r\n\r\nTheme : ".$user_theme."\r\n\r\nAnnee : ".$user_annee ;

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

if(!$send_mail)
{
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Merci, '.$user_prenom .' pour votre message. Je vous réponds très vite !'));
    die($output);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `.val()` and `[]` in name to get values of checkboxes in jquery

`$("input[name='id']:checked");`

to get selected values you can serialize them

`console.log($('input[name='id']:checked').serialize());`

or you can use each loop

`$('input[name='id']:checked').each(function() {
   console.log(this.value);
});`

or if you want to paas them through `ajax`

just add it in variable like

`var checked = $('input[name='id']:checked').serialize();`

or if you want to push it's values in array

`var checkboxValues = [];
$('input[name=id]:checked').map(function() {
            checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
});`